openbsd: Allow access to a certain interface only to root
I have several interfaces, one of them urndis0 is an external USB modem.
I want that only root could use it (i.e send packages through it), while other users would be unable to do so.
How to do it?

Untested, but
block quick on urndis0
pass on urndis0 proto {tcp, udp} user 0

should do the trick.
From pf.conf's man page:
 user user
         This rule only applies to packets of sockets owned by the
         specified user.  For outgoing connections initiated from the
         firewall, this is the user that opened the connection.  For
         incoming connections to the firewall itself, this is the user
         that listens on the destination port.

         When listening sockets are bound to the wildcard address, pf(4)
         cannot determine if a connection is destined for the firewall
         itself.  To avoid false matches on just the destination port,
         combine a user rule with source or destination address self.

         All packets, both outgoing and incoming, of one connection are
         associated with the same user and group.  Only TCP and UDP
         packets can be associated with users.

         The user and group arguments refer to the effective (as opposed
         to the real) IDs, in case the socket is created by a
         setuid/setgid process.  User and group IDs are stored when a
         socket is created; when a process creates a listening socket as
         root (for instance, by binding to a privileged port) and
         subsequently changes to another user ID (to drop privileges), the
         credentials will remain root.

         User and group IDs can be specified as either numbers or names.
         The syntax is similar to the one for ports.  The following
         example allows only selected users to open outgoing connections:

               block out proto tcp all
               pass  out proto tcp from self user { < 1000, dhartmei }

         The example below permits users with uid between 1000 and 1500 to
         open connections:

               block out proto tcp all
               pass  out proto tcp from self user { 999 >< 1501 }

         The ‘:’ operator, which works for port number matching, does not
         work for user and group match.

